# Cannot generate DSA/ECDH key with Curve25519 for use as an OpenPGP key using Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, openpgp, ecdh

I'm trying to generate an OpenPGP keyring using a DSA and a ECDH keypair combination using Bouncy Castle's Java APIs. In order not to rely on NIST curves, I have chosen Curve25519 to be the function I want to use. However, upon keyring export I get an `IllegalArgumentException`:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal object in getInstance: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DLSequence
>    at: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>    at: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaPGPKeyConverter.getPGPPublicKey(Unknown Source)
>    at: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaPGPKeyConverter.getPGPPublicKey(Unknown Source)
>    at: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaPGPKeyPair.getPublicKey(Unknown Source)
>    at: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaPGPKeyPair.(Unknown Source)
> ```

The code I'm using to generate both keypairs is as follows:

```java
String identity, passphrase;        // User input
OutputStream secretOut, publicOut;  // File streams

try {
    KeyPairGenerator dsaKeygen  = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance ("DSA", "BC");
    KeyPairGenerator ecdhKeygen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance ("ECDH", "BC");

    dsaKeygen.initialize (2048);
    KeyPair dsaKeypair = dsaKeygen.generateKeyPair ();

    X9ECParameters ecParams = CustomNamedCurves.getByName ("Curve25519");
    ECParameterSpec ecSpecs = new ECParameterSpec (
        ecParams.getCurve (),
        ecParams.getG (),
        ecParams.getN (),
        ecParams.getH (),
        ecParams.getSeed ()
    );

    ecdhKeygen.initialize (ecSpecs, new SecureRandom ());
    KeyPair ecdhKeypair = ecdhKeygen.generateKeyPair ();

    PGPKeyPair dsaPgpKeypair  = new JcaPGPKeyPair (PGPPublicKey.DSA, dsaKeypair, new Date ());
    PGPKeyPair ecdhPgpKeypair = new JcaPGPKeyPair (PGPPublicKey.ECDH, ecdhKeypair, new Date ()); // Fails

    PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator flagsGen = new PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator ();
    flagsGen.setKeyFlags (
        true,
        KeyFlags.CERTIFY_OTHER | 
            KeyFlags.SIGN_DATA | 
            KeyFlags.ENCRYPT_COMMS |
            KeyFlags.ENCRYPT_STORAGE
    );

    PGPDigestCalculator sha1Calculator = new JcaPGPDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder ()
        .build ()
        .get (HashAlgorithmTags.SHA1);

    PGPKeyRingGenerator keyRingGenerator = new PGPKeyRingGenerator (
        PGPSignature.POSITIVE_CERTIFICATION,
        dsaPgpKeypair,
        identity,
        sha1Calculator,
        flagsGenerator.generate (),
        null,
        new JcaPGPContentSignerBuilder (dsaPgpKeypair.getPublicKey ().getAlgorithm (), AlgorithmTags.SHA1),
        new JcePBESecretKeyEncryptorBuilder (PGPEncryptedDate.AES_256, sha1Calculator)
            .setProvider ("BC")
            .build (passphrase.toCharArray ())
    );

    keyRingGenerator.addSubKey (ecdhPgpKeypair);

    keyRingGenerator.generateSecretKeyRing ().encode (secretOut);
    secretOut.close ();

    keyRingGenerator.generatePublicKeyRing ().encode (publicOut);
    publicOut.close ();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // obligatory exception handling
}
```

For reference: The code generating the Curve25519 key I adapted from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/251#issuecomment-345512382) and the code generating and exporting the whole keyring I adapted from [this Bouncy Castle example](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/DSAElGamalKeyRingGenerator.java).

However, above code works and exports an importable keyring (well, not importable into GnuPG because SHA1 is only supported by Bouncy Castle for key checksum generation) using curves from the `ECNamedCurveTable`, for example `prime256v1`.

Why does the conversion between a JCA keypair and an OpenPGP keypair fail for keys created using Curve25519, but not those created with specs from `ECNamedCurveTable`? Am I missing something or are custom curves not supported by Bouncy Castle for OpenPGP keys?

Comment: I have the same problem: Ec25519 is not in the OpenPGP RFC! It is a draft: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-openpgp-rfc4880bis-04 . So it isn't implemented yet. It would be nice to find a workaround for Java using Ec25519.